# Named Parameters in MySQL Workbench Queries?

Tags: mysql-workbench

In OpenOffice / LibreOffice I'm used to added `:prefixed-parameter-names` to my queries.

For example:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id = :id
```

Is there a similar functionality in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SET @given_id = 1;
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id = @given_id ;
```